# Powershell add a header on output in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, header

I'm sure this is very simple but I can't seem to get it. All i'm trying to do is add a header/title to the object being returned/exported so it's more readable in the end product.

What I have now:

```
$name | foreach {
Get-MailboxPermission $_ |? {$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -ne "False"} | Select User | export-csv -path $path -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
```

This gives me an output that looks like:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

However for the sake of easy reading, I want it to say the name of the mailbox it's showing the permissions for, so like this:

```
Mailbox 1
name1
name2
name3

Mailbox 2
name1
name2
name3
```

I hope that make sense, any assistance is always very appreciated.

Thanks,
Lou

Comment: You want your output file to look like that? Note that it won't be a valid CSV file anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want a CSV you'll have to output $name to each line, resulting in

```
Mailbox;User    
$name1;$user1
$name1;$user2
$name2;$user1
$name2;$user2
```

After that you'll be able to use filters in Excel.

You can try this

```
$result = @()

$record = @{

    "Mailbox" = ""
    "User" = ""

}

$name | foreach {
$user = Get-MailboxPermission $_ |? {$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -ne "False"} | Select User

$record.Mailbox = $_
$record.User = $user
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -Property $record
$result += $objRecord

}

$result | Export-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```